# Is there any danger to including functional corrections in git merge commits?

Tags: git, version-control

Suppose I have two branches. The ancestor of both is the following:

```
var myobject = Custom();

function performTask1(){
    myobject.performTask('1');
}
```

Now I create branch 'A' where I make the following changes:

```
var myobject = Custom();

function performTask1(){
    myobject.performTask('1');
}

function performTask2(){
    myobject.performTask('2');
}
```

Then I create branch 'B' where I make the following changes:

```
var taskPerformer = Custom();

function performTask1(){
    taskPerformer.performTask('1');
}

function performTask3(){
    taskPerformer.performTask('3');
}
```

Then I merge branch 'A' onto branch 'B' and I get a conflict:

```
var taskPerformer = Custom();

function performTask1(){
    taskPerformer.performTask('1');
}

<<<<<<<<<<<< HEAD
function performTask3(){
    taskPerformer.performTask('3');
}
=================
function performTask2(){
    myobject.performTask('2');
}
>>>>>>>>>>>>> A
```

I want to eventually have a file that looks like this:

```
var taskPerformer = Custom();

function performTask1(){
    taskPerformer.performTask('1');
}

function performTask3(){
    taskPerformer.performTask('3');
}

function performTask2(){
    taskPerformer.performTask('2');
}
```

However, that includes changing the line

```
    myobject.performTask('2');
```

to

```
    taskPerformer.performTask('2');
```

Should I do this during the merge? Or should I only resolve conflicts, and then make functional corrections on the following commit?

Update 1:

My concerns are not with conventions, but with practical version control. Does the merge typically "just work" when mixing changes that are specific to conflict resolution with changes that have more to do with the function of the program? Is adding another commit "safer" somehow when merging changes between branches?

Comment: Ask your team lead/rest of the team. I usually amend it to the merge commit but I wouldn't mind adding a "fix merge" commit. It's just too unimportant to me to favor one thing strongly over the other.

Comment: Do you feel that there is no difference in terms of tracking changes? Suppose that there are 5 other branches that these changes are being swapped between, and merges are happening on all those branches as well. Does either approach have some benefit then?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "best practices", is too subjetive and then there is no way to precise answer this

Comment: I edited it to try and be a little less subjective. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICS if you would just resolve the conflict, the code wouldn't work, because the variable myobject doesn't exist anymore, do i see that right? If so, then i think it would be totally ok to change also the variable names (i would still call that conflict resolution, because the change is still caused by the conflict).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit subjective I'm afraid.... However, I'd suspect that most teams wouldn't want broken code checked in, and therefore you'd want to fix it during the merge.

I'd want this fixed prior to check in in the most efficient way possible. And then, follow up commits could refine or improve as needed. Examples might be refactoring to reduce redundancy or what have. But I'm getting off topic.

Again, this is up to to the team but most teams (AFAIK) would would this fixed prior to commit.

Comment: Suppose the complexity level gets ramped up a bit, and its not just one branch, but five or six, and the order of merges is not necessarily the same (A->B, B->A) From the perspective of making our lives easier is there a benefit one way or the other? Does it not matter?

Comment: That's where you start getting in to the subjective and situational nature of the question. I would say if there is sufficient complexity or even risk, then then yes, it matters and it won't hurt to check in a (what I would consider) partial merge. And then clean it up in follow up commits.

Answer (score 0):

The change you describe is not functional. The variable name is not functional, it is for the developer.  So I would have no issue changing the variable name in this case to have working code.  As others have pointed out the goal should be to have working code when you are done.  If there was a but, say for instance the 'B' branch had this code:
var taskPerformer = Custom();

```
function performTask1(){
    taskPerformer.performTask('1');
}

function performTask3(){
    taskPerformer.performTask('A');
}
```

I would argue that you should complete the merge, making note of the bug, then fix the bug in a separate commit.  The reason I suggest this is that the bug now has visibility in the history of the repository.  So people who may be seeing the behavior can find the commit that resolves it.

Hope that helps,

Pat O